# cpupower and libcpupower

Tags: cpu-frequency

cpupower fails sometime to execute with this error :

```
cpupower: error while loading shared libraries: libcpupower.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've compiled and installed the last cpupower tool from sources on my workstation.

The Makefile install command installs the libs in /usr/local/lib and my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set accordingly :

```
syl@WorkStation-T3500:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/usr/local/lib/

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     20 juin  26 11:46 libcpupower.so -> libcpupower.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     20 juin  26 11:46 libcpupower.so.0 -> libcpupower.so.0.0.1
```

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  77048 juin  26 11:46 libcpupower.so.0.0.1
l

A simple cpupower info query works nice :

```
syl@WorkStation-T3500:~$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
driver: intel_pstate
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.20 GHz
available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.20 GHz.
              The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
current CPU frequency: 1.20 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
boost state support:
Supported: yes
Active: yes
```

Nervetheless, here is what happens when I try to set some policy :

```
syl@WorkStation-T3500:~$ sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor userspace
cpupower: error while loading shared libraries: libcpupower.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

May I ask you some hints about this strange issue ?

All the best

Sylvain

Comment: Is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH set correctly for the root user?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that LD_LIBRARY_PATH proper initialization is not enough, I had to add the lib path into /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf :

```
syl@WorkStation-T3500:~$ sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf

# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/loca/lib/
```

Then  :

```
syl@WorkStation-T3500:~$ sudo ldconfig
```

Which  makes the thing work, but I cannot understand this :

```
 syl@WorkStation-T3500:~$ sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor userspace Setting cpu: 0
Error setting new values. Common errors:
- Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
- Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
- Trying to set an invalid policy?
- Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?
```

Ok, nothing remains except to understand why this command is not operational...

Cheers !

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

The `intel_pstate` driver accepts only `powersave` or `performance` policy governors, not `userspace`. This restriction is enforced [in the `<kernel source>/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c` file, by function `intel_pstate_verify_policy`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c?h=v4.17.3#n1827):

```
static int intel_pstate_verify_policy(struct cpufreq_policy *policy)
{
        struct cpudata *cpu = all_cpu_data[policy->cpu];

        update_turbo_state();
        cpufreq_verify_within_limits(policy, policy->cpuinfo.min_freq,
                                     intel_pstate_get_max_freq(cpu));

        if (policy->policy != CPUFREQ_POLICY_POWERSAVE &&
            policy->policy != CPUFREQ_POLICY_PERFORMANCE)
                return -EINVAL;

        intel_pstate_adjust_policy_max(policy, cpu);

        return 0;
}
```

If you really need to use the `userspace` governor, you'll need to switch to another CPUFreq driver. [See this question for more details.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/153693/258991)

Comment: Many thanks for this hint, yes I came accross this point googling.